# Can't reference MySQL by column names

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling to reference the MySQL data simultaneously by both column name and individual row number.

The code sample below does the following;

Successfully

- prints the correct data to a table when looping through the whole table, referencing columns by name OR number.
- when referencing individual rows in the database the correct columns by the column number

But I can't get it to successfully reference individual rows (by number) and columns (by name) at the same time.

Apologies if this is a ridiculous question, I'm new to PHP and MySQL.

I think my description is abysmal, so maybe this will help. Of the four options available (column either by name or number, and rows either individually or looping through a group) it works like this;

- Column by number, each row in a loop. Yes.
- Column by name, each row in a loop. Yes.
- Column by number, individual row. Yes.
- Column by name, individual row. NO! (as shown in the last line of code, **a** is a column in my database)

Does anyone please have any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<t

h>Lastname</th>
<th>test</th>
<th>order</th>
</tr>";
$ind = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .  ($row['age'] * 1)  . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . ($row['a']) . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $ind. "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $ind += 1;
}
echo "</table>";

$sql="SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY PID";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {

  // Prints single entry AP    
  print "<br>";

  $rowNumber = $id;
  mysqli_data_seek($result, $rowNumber);//start row is whatever you need to be the first row
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

  print "<br>";
//-----------------------------------------------------
  $mathString = $row[1];
  $description = $row[4];
  echo "math string:" . $mathString . "<br>";
  echo "a is said to equal:" . $description . " - " . $row['a'];
```

Comment: Where is `$id` coming from?

Comment: That's from the URL.

Comment: just add a where clause and rerun the query, select * from tablename where id= value

Comment: Sorry, @VeNoMiS, would you mind elaborating a little? Should I do this purely for the individual row? What's the purpose of 'id= value'?

Comment: read about sql where clause [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) and yes it's only for the "single" row

Comment: Thanks, @VeNoMiS. I ended up using [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp) instead as it was more clearly focused towards MySQL and PHP.

Comment: [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) only returns an array with number-index, as the documentation says, so the "a" field isn't accessible in the way you're doing